# Sum of counts for nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, counter-cache, awesome-nested-set

I have two models: **Category** and **Ad**. **Category has_many :ads** + I added **counter cache :ads_count**. I use **gem awesome_nested_set** to make nested categories, so Category1 can be parent/child of Category2 which can be parent of Category3 etc. What I need for my categories#index is to calculate total sum of ads which belong to certain category or child category(or "grandchild" etc). My solution for now is: **some_nested_categories.sum(:ads_count)**. But let's say if I have many many categories in my index page, it makes many queries to retrieve all that data and it takes too long. How can I make this more efficiently? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend the idea of the `counter_cache` manually for a sort of `sum_cache`, lets call it `nested_ads_count`.

Then there would be 4 general cases that need to be handled

- a category gets a new add
- a category is "Moved/added" to a new parent category"
- a category gets deleted (or removed from a parent)"

An `after_update` callback that updates the parent's `nested_ads_count` when either the current's `nested_ads_count` or `ads_count` updates. solves the first case.

awesome_nested_set solves the other 2 cases

using an `after_add` and `after_remove` callbacks recalculate the `nested_ads_count`.

The method to calculate and cache the `nested_ads_count` would look like this

```
def reset_nested_ads_count
  self.nested_ads_count = some_nested_categories.sum(:nested_ads_count) + self.ads_count
end
```

This method is optimal when the frequency that the count is used is greater than the frequency that it is updated, as it only does the time expensive queries when the number would be updated, and not when the number needs to be seen.

There is one possible pitfall that can happen and that is if you have a loop in your nesting (a > b > a, or even more insidious a > b > c > ... > a) you can get yourself in an infinite loop.  I have not seen anything explicitly stating that awesome_nested_set blocks this case.